# What is it called when you analyze the grouping of variables? How to do it in Excel?

Tags: clustering, excel

I have 5 columns of data in an Excel spreadsheet.

Each row has either 1 or 0 (on or off) within each column.

I'm trying to determine the most common grouping or clustering of columns that have a 1. For example, it could be columns B & D are the most common grouping that have 1s, followed by columns A, D & E, etc.

What is this method of analysis called and how do I do it in Excel?

Comment: You'll have to be clearer about what you mean by "most common grouping"

Comment: Your question is rather unclear but in general grouping any kind of similar objects would be called _clustering_.

Comment: I don't really have a great way to explain it other than trying to find the clustering patterns in the columns.  Hoping there is an easy way to do it.

Comment: By common grouping I mean which columns are most commonly grouped together (i.e. have 1 instead of 0).  It could be column B & D, for example, or columns A, D & E, etc.  Trying to find the most common grouping patterns for the columns.

Comment: Do you mean columns that have the same number of 1's and 0's? columns that have a 1's and 0's on the same rows?

Comment: Yes. Patterns of columns that have the same number of 1's and 0's in the same positions.  What are those patterns and how many of each?

Answer (score 5):

The number of places in which two 0-1 arrays `A` and `B` (of the same length) both have ones is readily computed as

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A,B)
```

This generalizes: for three 0-1 arrays `A`, `B`, and `C` use `=SUMPRODUCT(A,B,C)`, and so on.

The rest is a matter of systematically referencing all possible combinations of your variables so that you don't have to write $2^5=32$ different such formulas.  To this end, I will suppose the data are organized in a standard way: each variable is a column; the first row in each column contains the variable name; no rows are blank or skipped; and all columns have the same number of entries.  I will further suppose these data are *contiguous* so that they form a rectangular array.

In Excel, as in almost all computing systems, it is advantageous to use meaningful names for data.  Let us, then, name this array of data (*without its first row of names*) `Data`.  We will want to be able to index the columns by numbers.  Excel prefers to start indexes with $0$, so that the zeroth index will be the leftmost column, index $1$ will refer to the second-to-the-left, and so on.  Although there are various ways to do this, a convenient one uses `OFFSET`: `OFFSET(Data, 0, 0, , 1)` is the left column of data, `OFFSET(Data, 0, 1, , 1)` is the next column, and so on.  You can see that the third argument of `OFFSET` is the one that picks out the column.  In this way, for instance, the formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(Data,0,0,,1), OFFSET(Data,0,1,,1))
```

computes the number of places in which the leftmost two columns (with indexes $0$ and $1$) both have ones.

The formulas still vary too much: they will have between two and five arguments, depending on how many columns are involved.  To make things easier to enter, I suggest a little trick: *create a column of all ones.*  It must have exactly the same number of entries as all the others, but it need not be contiguous with them: let's simply name it `One`.  When you treat this as if it were are variable, *including it in the `SUMPRODUCT` formula changes nothing.*  Therefore, we can write a *single* formula involving all five columns in which each column is used when needed and otherwise is replaced by the column of ones.  Here is the formula (created with a lot of copy-and-paste, of course, so it's not as difficult to write as it might look):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(MID(I2,1,1)="1", OFFSET(Data,0,0,,1), One),
            IF(MID(I2,2,1)="1", OFFSET(Data,0,1,,1), One), 
            IF(MID(I2,3,1)="1", OFFSET(Data,0,2,,1), One), 
            IF(MID(I2,4,1)="1", OFFSET(Data,0,3,,1), One), 
            IF(MID(I2,5,1)="1", OFFSET(Data,0,4,,1), One))
```

The expressions `MID(I2,1,1)`, *etc*, are binary codes "00000", "00001", "00010", ..., through "11111" indicating all possible combinations of the columns "A" through "E".  They are easy to generate from a list of the integers $0, 1, \ldots, 2^5-1=31$ using the `DEC2BIN` function.  `MID` picks out each binary digit in turn.  The `IF` expressions use the corresponding column for the calculation whenever the digit is a $1$ and otherwise use the default column of ones, as explained.

To make this more readable we may also choose to convert the binary codes into lists of their corresponding columns.  Because that's a peripheral detail, I won't go into the method here, but you can see it in the screenshots below.

Upon hiding some of the intermediate calculations and sorting the results (`COUNT`) in descending order, the spreadsheet will look like this:

[image: Spreadsheet]

The first value of `Count` tells us how many data rows there are.  The entries for "A", "B", ..., "E" count the total numbers of ones for each variable.  After them come the entries for combinations of variables.  *E.g.*, "C" and "E" have $31$ ones in common, then "A" and "C" have $28$ in common, and so on.  I believe this is the information the question asks for.  It is one way to represent a $2^5$ *cross-tabulation.*

The blue text, by the way, indicates original (raw) data.  The bold black text displays the results.  Intermediate calculations, shown below, are neither blue nor bold.

[image: Expanded spreadsheet columns]

`Index` was a list of $0, 1, \ldots, 2^5-1$ before the results were sorted by decreasing `Count`.  `Code` is its base-2 representation.  The next five columns (J:N) are used ultimately to show the information under the `Columns` header: which variables are designated by each `Code`.

All formulas are the same in each row: they were entered in the first data row and then just propagated down through 31 more rows to complete the table before it was sorted.  Moreover, the formulas appear in two groups of five: columns J:N and columns O:S.  Those were created from a single formula each, copied, pasted, and suitably modified for each column. Here they are:

[image: Formulas]

---

Those wishing to compare this solution with those developed using a statistical computing platform, consider this one in `R`, whose input `x` is a data frame object with (at least) five columns:

```
b <- c(FALSE,TRUE)
subsets <- as.matrix(expand.grid(A=b, B=b, C=b, D=b, E=b))
rownames(subsets) <- apply(subsets, 1, function(i) 
    paste(colnames(x)[i, drop=FALSE], sep="", collapse=""))
sort(apply(subsets, 1, function(i) 
    sum(apply(x[, i, drop=FALSE], 1, function(y) min(c(1,y)) > 0))), decreasing=TRUE)
```

You can see the same computations happening (although some of the details are buried in `expand.grid`, just as I buried them in the hidden columns of the spreadsheet, and the product of ones and zeros has been replaced by a check of their minimum value because that's simpler to code in `R`).  I find the Excel solution convenient to implement when the data are already in a spreadsheet, but it is a little risky to code and rather difficult and unreliable to apply to another dataset whose dimensions might be different or which might have missing values.

Comment: Using correlation would handle 0 and 1 equally, so that a column of all 1's is not treated as being the item most similar to everything else.  There are only 13 nontrivial partitions of five objects, so it is feasible and probably desirable to do some of the analysis by hand taking other criteria into account.

Comment: @zyx I haven't a clue what you meant in that comment. :-) Maybe it would be constructive to note that the column of 1's is not intended to have any interpretation: it is there to expedite the computations, nothing more. Although it is possible to think of many alternative approaches to this problem, I simply cannot fathom what you might actually mean by doing something "by hand" or by "other criteria." If you would care to elaborate in your answer--comments are not the place for that--then I'm sure it would be a welcome improvement.

Comment: I meant the extreme case (to illustrate the problem) in which one of the five data columns A,B,C,D, or E happens to contain only 1's.  Using criteria based on "shared values of 1" as the basis for determining the clustering, this column would be deemed most similar to, and should cluster with, all others, even though it is independent of all of them.  Correlation is not as susceptible to this problem.

Comment: @xyz I do not see how that could be correct: in your hypothetical case, that column of all 1's would have a count equal to the number of records. The other columns would, presumably, have different counts. Thus counts of shared ones will distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this just once, for only five columns, with a fixed set of data, you might be better off calculating the correlation between pairs of columns and using that plus knowledge of the problem and the data to decide how to group the columns, by hand.

If it is a more general and recurring type of problem, this is the general clustering problem and you could (for example) compute some notion of distance between pairs of columns and run a clustering algorithm on that, or look for hierarchical clustering if you want to retain the idea that one subset of columns is closer among its members than another subset.

Comment: Excel can compute inter-column correlations but I don't know if there is any clustering functionality.  The usual method to do anything complicated with a spreadsheet is to export it to a CSV file that can be processed by statistical software such as **R**.